# How do I put this program in a loop

Tags: java, arrays

I want to make a Tic tac toe game in Dr Java.

1. I ask you for a number between 0-8. You choose a number 5.
2. Then it should print out the tic tac toe board where 5 will be replaced by X.
3. Then I ask you again for a number between 0-8. Say you choose 3.
4. It should then show the tic tac toe board where 5 and 3 will be replaced by X.

It will be great if you can help with this program.

By the way, this is only the method and I still have to write the main body.

This is my Code done in Dr Java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToeArray {

  public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int [] A1 = {0,1,2};
    int [] A2 = {3,4,5};
    int [] A3 = {6,7,8};
    int [] A4 = {0,3,6};
    int [] A5 = {1,4,7};
    int [] A6 = {2,5,8};
    int [] A7 = {0,4,8};
    int [] A8 = {2,4,6};


    System.out.println("Player #1: Please enter a number between 0-8");
    int playerOne = in.nextInt();  

    if (playerOne == A1 [0]){
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    X      |    1     |     2    ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");    
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    3      |    4     |     5    ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");      
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    6      |    7     |     8    ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");


    }else if (playerOne ==A1 [2]){
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    0      |    1     |    X     ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");    
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    3      |    4     |     5    ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");      
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    6      |    7     |     8    ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");

    }else if (playerOne ==A2 [0]){
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    0      |    1     |    2     ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");    
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    X      |    4     |     5    ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");      
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    6      |    7     |     8    ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");


    }else if (playerOne ==A2 [1]){
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    0      |    1     |    2     ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");    
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    3      |    X     |     5    ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");      
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    6      |    7     |     8    ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");


    }else if (playerOne ==A2 [2]){
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    0      |    1     |    2     ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");    
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    3      |    4     |    X     ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");      
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    6      |    7     |     8    ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");


    }else if (playerOne ==A3 [0]){
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    0      |    1     |    2     ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");    
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    3      |    4     |    5     ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");      
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    X      |    7     |     8    ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");


    }else if (playerOne ==A3 [1]){
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    0      |    1     |    2     ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");    
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    3      |    4     |    5     ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");      
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    6      |    X     |     8    ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          "); 

    }else if (playerOne ==A3 [2]){
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    0      |    1     |    2     ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");    
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    3      |    4     |    5     ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");      
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    6      |    7     |     X    ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");

    }else {
      System.out.println("Try Again");

    }
    return -1;
  }
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely different languages. Please ensure you only choose tags related to your actual problem. I've fixed it for you this time.

Comment: That's a lot of typing...

Comment: So can you help me do this thing.

Comment: hmmmm can you make the question more clear ? and I feel the question title is unrelated

Comment: "It will be great if you can help with this program." is not a question.  Stack Overflow will answer specific questions arising out of homework, but it will not do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

While its not a good question..
but here's what you wanted just keep all the logic in a loop whose condition is always correct.. like this..

```
while ( true ) {
   int playerOne = in.nextInt();  

   if (playerOne == A1 [0]){
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");
      System.out.println("    X      |    1     |     2    ");
      System.out.println("           |          |          ");    
      System.out.println("  -------------------------------");   
        //......
        // All other if conditions here
        //......

       else {
         System.out.println("Try Again");
            }
     }  //Means include all data in loop while (true)
      return -1;
    }
```

It will run forever you have to break it manually by some condition. 
like

```
        if (tries == 5)
            break ;
```

Comment: How do I check it now. By check I mean, Say you entered 2, now the 2 will be replaced with X and I ask you another time, U entered 1, What do I need to write in order to print the previous tic tac board and the current Board.

Answer (score 0):

Here how you should use a while loop. Since you need to do something here didn't put my wins() method logic here. You can write your own one.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[][] ttt = new char[][] {
           {'N', 'N', 'N'},
           {'N', 'N', 'N'},
           {'N', 'N', 'N'}
    };

    int i=0;
    boolean result = false;
    while (i<9) {
        String s = scanner.next();
        try {
           int number = Integer.parseInt(s);
           if (number > 8) {
              System.out.println("Number greater than 8.");
              continue;
           }

           char playerCharacter;
           if (i%2 == 0) {
              playerCharacter = 'X';  
           } else {
              playerCharacter = 'O';
           }

           int row = number / 3;
           int col = number % 3;

           if (ttt[row][col] == 'X' || ttt[row][col] == 'Y') {
               System.out.println("Entered place already taken.");
               continue;  
           }

           if (win(ttt, row, col)) {
               System.out.println(playerCharacter + " wins");
               result = true;
               break;
           }


        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Number entered is incorrect.");
            continue;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (!result) {
        System.out.println("Match drawn");   
    }
```

Comment: How do I check it now. By check I mean, Say you entered 2, now the 2 will be replaced with X and I ask you another time,  U entered 1, What do I need to write in order to print the previous tic tac board and the current Board.